# Can multiple users commit to SVN simultaneously? Is it thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, svn, thread-safety, svnkit, multi-user

The application must be desgined in such a way that it must support multiple users while commiting into SVN Repositiry. I'm done with the application and the related stuff, however, i'm stuck with this multi-user thing. **How i can achieve this?** I saw somewhere that *for every thread you have to instantiate a separate SVNRepository driver.* This tell **it's not thread safe**..or may be i'm getting the whole thing wrong. Any help on this issue is appreciated. thanks.

I get the above info (the one in italics) from [Here](http://svnkit.com/kb/dev-guide-multithreaded-environment.html) .

Comment: The link you refer to is specific to SVNKit. Apache Subversion itself obviously supports simultaneous commits. It makes sense to read SVNBook before developing a SVN client http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html

Comment: @bahrep and what about simultaneous commits of the same revision no.?

Comment: @Vinayak - same rev just impossible. Commit is atomic operation and two commit will be different transactions server-side

Comment: If two users attempt to commit simultaneously, the first to arrive at the server (they will never arrive at *precisely* the same time) will be handled while the second waits for it to complete. If the first commit is successful and modifies any paths that the second also modifies, the transaction will be rejected by the server, telling that second user to run `svn update` before retrying.

Comment: @LazyBadger so how i can handle this situation where multiple users want to check in at the same time? for example if user A commits and at same time user B does the same...the first thing comes into my mind regarding handling this issue is to show a message to user B that checkin is in progress and have to wait for sometime. Or, use different SVNRepository objects everytime the user commits!?!? *confused* i think threading is the answer to this but anyway..

Comment: You can trust in SVN - it will allow only single fist (fastest) commit. For the rest (in case of identical URL) it will return error "Resource outdated, please update" (can't recall exact text and error-code, but commits will fail) and you have to process this case

Comment: @LazyBadger  right it gives the following error: *svn:Commit Failed. File or directory is out of date; try updating*

Comment: do you have real working copies with changes or do you want to create commits without working copies (i.e. on the fly, like "svn mkdir http://url/path/dir" does)?

Comment: @DmitryPavlenko real working copies with changes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm SVNKit developer, let me explain how the things work.

SVNRepository class represents one SVN connection with it's own credentials. It is thread-unsafe that means that you can perform only sequential operations on it. See this article for more details:

http://vcs.atspace.co.uk/2012/09/21/are-svnkit-methods-reenterable/

So if your application tries to create several commits at the same time, you should use several independent SVNRepository instances. Good news is that no special synchronization code is required, all synchronization is performed on the server side. Another good news is that when commit for a certain SVNRepository object is finished or cancelled, you can reuse the connection to start another commit. But note that if you use http protocol, you can't reuse the same connection to commit on behalf another user even if you change credentials for the connection (SVNRepository#setAuthenticationManager).

To create a commit without working copy use SVNRepository#getCommitEditor which starts the commit transaction. To stop the transaction use either ISVNCommitEditor#closeEdit or ISVNCommitEditor#abortEdit; you can perform other operations on SVNRepository instance, until commit transaction is finished.

ISVNCommitEditor instance should describe your virtual working copy: it tells to SVNKit about your current knowledge of the latest working copy state. If the description doesn't correspond to the real latest change you get "File or directory is out of date; try updating" error.

http://vcs.atspace.co.uk/2012/07/20/subversion-remote-api-committing-without-working-copy/

You can use -1 instead of real revision in ISVNEditor#openFile/openDir to disable checks, but that can cause another problem: you could overwrite changes without knowing about them.

Another option is to commit using real working copies and real changes on filesystem (using SvnOperationFactory#createCommit). But even in this case have a look at the first link to learn which objects can/can't be reused across threads.

Hope this helps, if you have other questions, feel free to ask on SVNKit mailing list.